# iosの子供向けカテゴリでFirebaseを利用するには

Tags: firebase

Firebaseを使用してiosの子供向けカテゴリのアプリを作成しています

2019年6月3日のUpdates to the App Store Review GuidelinesでGuidelines 1.3 and 5.1.4が更新されましたが、
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06032019j

こちらで、

> Guidelines 1.3 and 5.1.4. In order to help keep kids’ data private, apps in the kids category and apps intended for kids cannot include third-party advertising or analytics software and may not transmit data to third parties.
>
> ガイドライン1.3と5.1.4。 子供のデータを非公開にするために、子供向けカテゴリのアプリや子供向けのアプリに第三者の広告や分析ソフトウェアを含めることはできず、第三者にデータを送信することはできません。

と記載されています。

Firebase Coreをインストールすると同時にインストールされているFirebase Analyticsは、
ガイドラインに記載されているthird-party analytics softwareに該当すると思われますが、
自前で代わりのサーバーを用意するのが困難な状況にあるため、解決策を2つ考えてみたのですが、
これらの解決策はそもそもFirebaseで可能なのでしょうか。

1.FirebaseアナリティクスをApple審査で問題がなさそうな形で利用する。
　・必要なそうな事
　　a.Firebaseアナリティクス　SDKでIDFAやIP等、特定のデータを取得しないようにする。
　　b.Firebaseアナリティクス　SDKからイベントを送るが、ユーザー属性は分析はしないようにする。

2.Firebaseアナリティクスだけ利用せずBigQueryを利用する。
　・必要なそうな事
　　a.Firebase CoreをインストールしてもFirebaseアナリティクスがインストールされないようにする。
　　b.Firebaseアナリティクス以外のFirebaseの機能を利用してBiqQueryにトラッキングしたデータを取り込む。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

こんにちは。

時間がたってからのレスポンスとなりますがご容赦ください

現状ではガイドライン上で、一部のサードパーティの解析ソフトウェアが
許可されていることが明記されています。

iOS向けのSDKも更新されクラス名やメソッド名を更新するなどして対応を行ったようです。

ですので現時点ではFireBase AnlyticsのiOSアプリへの組み込みとKIDSカテゴリへの公開は問題なくなっていると思われます。

https://developer.apple.com/jp/app-store/review/guidelines/#safety
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5153